# Sytax Error with awk when periods in field separator

Tags: awk

I have fields of data separated as:

`root.chain1.chain2.chain3.field.0:` `<data>`

I have tried to use awk on the command line as:

`awk -F "." -f inputFile '{print $1}'`

But it tells me there is a syntax error on the second period.

I also tried

`awk -f inputFile '{ FS = "\." ; print $1}'`

but I get the same syntax error.

So then I tried:

`awk -f inputFile '{ FS = "."; sub(/^[^:]*:[:blank:]*/, ""); print}'`

because I ultimately want what is in `<data>`, but I get the same syntax error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-f inputfile` tells awk to INTERPRET inputfile as a awk script...
 try to :

```
awk -F "." '{print $1}'  inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You must give the input file after the code argument, e.g.

```
awk -F "." '{print $1}' inputFile
```